# Unable to add a security group of a different account into ingress rule of my account's security group though both VPC are peered

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am unable to add a Security Group of a different account into ingress rule of my account's Security Group though both VPC are peered.

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --profile=abc  --region=ap-south-1 --group-id sg-0ab15b167d88bxxxx --protocol tcp --port 3306 --source-group 08720304xxxx/sg-0a6a5c2183956xxxx
```

> An error occurred (VPCIdNotSpecified) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: No default VPC for this user

I was expecting my new security group should have been allowed.

Comment: The error message is saying that you require a **Default VPC** in that Region. Related: [Adding custom cidr to ingress security group using Lambda without default vpc | AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUTsGZ74tZSdeRAbv3GKm4Uw/adding-custom-cidr-to-ingress-security-group-using-lambda-without-default-vpc)

Comment: Both VPCs should be in the same region. Follow this for more detail - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-security-groups.html

Comment: Both are in same region

Comment: And we have deleted default VPCs from the account

Comment: As per the above re:Post article, you will need to [create a default VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html#create-default-vpc).

Answer (score 1):

does this error shows up with both default VPC as well? 
It looks there are a few API calls that rely on having one even if you're not using it.
[How do I create, delete, or restore a default VPC in Amazon VPC?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/deleted-default-vpc) should help you creating a default VPC.

You could try creating back the default VPC to verify if the error message persists.